# Error while deploying kubeless function to kubernetes cluster by using serverless framework

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, serverless-framework, faas, kubeless

I am trying to deploy a kubeless function using serverless. I created a kubernetes cluster using minikube and I am trying to follow this [link](https://medium.com/bitnami-perspectives/deploying-a-kubeless-function-using-serverless-templates-2d03f49b70e2) following which

1. I installed serverless
2. created a template kubeless-nodejs
3. installed plugins with `npm install`
4. and tried to deploy using `serverless deploy -v`

but I am getting an error

```
/home/vin/serverless/kube/services/email/node_modules/serverless-kubeless/lib/config.js:56
  return JSON.parse(this.configMag.data[key]);
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'runtime-images' of undefined
    at Config.get (/home/vin/serverless/kube/services/email/node_modules/serverless-kubeless/lib/config.js:56:44)
```

Please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I had to deploy kubeless to the Kubernetes cluster
I had to do this for that:

```
$ export RELEASE=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubeless/kubeless/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)
$ kubectl create ns kubeless
$ kubectl create -f https://github.com/kubeless/kubeless/releases/download/$RELEASE/kubeless-$RELEASE.yaml
```

as given here [link](https://kubeless.io/docs/quick-start/)